# Why should I use front-end plugins with my sbt playframework project?

Tags: angularjs, scala, playframework, sbt, sbt-web

If I have an angularjs frontend and am using play in the backend, why do people use the various sbt-plugins?

I understand how to use them, to compile the frontend etc. but isn't it better just to seperate the 2 projects completely and just use the native frontend tools like npm, bower, etc. ?

I'm trying to understand if there is some advantage to using the sbt plugins.

Comment: I think the sbt plugins are simpler for projects with a relatively small amount of front-end code for which a separate build process would be overkill.

Comment: I agree with @jazmit here.SBT will only be helpful when you have a thin frontend layer,maybe just for prototyping with only few dependencies.Once they become large,it becomes a pain to find and maintain libraries with SBT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sbt-web tools are useful when:

1. You have a small amount of front-end code, so that it's not worth setting up a separate build & deployment infrastructure for it
2. When you have shared code and/or compiled-in data between client and server, eg: javascript model code running in Nashorn as well as the browser, ScalaJS code interoperating with javascript
3. When you have fixed data (eg: internationalization tables) that are compiled into both client and server
4. When you have written unit tests in Scala for front-end code (eg: using ScalaCheck to [property-check javascript](https://jazmit.github.io/2015/01/10/scalacheck-nashorn.html))
5. When your dev team is already familiar with sbt, but not with other tools